# How to call a function in a class and then continue the test using that browser instance with selenium python?

Tags: python, class, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a problem in selenium python. I have a main test script and I'm calling a function called `LoginTestProject`, (this navigates to a page, and clicks some links). After this function has done its operation, I want the main script to continue the test using the same browser. How is this done?

Here's my code:

Class:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def LoginTestProject():
     global driver
     # Navigate to the App
     driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     driver.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news')
     driver.maximize_window()
     wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
     time.sleep(2)
     # Find and click the button to go to world section
     button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="orb-modules"]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a')
     button.click()
     time.sleep(2)
     # Find and click the button to Navigate to  Africa section
     button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="orb-modules"]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/a').click()
     return driver  # Return the logged-in browser instance
     time.sleep(2)
```

TestFile:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from TestingProject.Pages.Login2 import OpenPage

#Calls the function from the class to navigate to page
LoginTestProject()

#Continue with test, its failing to find the below element
button2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'///*[@id="topos-component"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/h3').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`return driver` ends the `LoginTestProject` so the last `time.sleep(2)` doesn't run.

Look into implicit waits and other waiting strategies to avoid using `time.sleep` at all.

Comment: HI thanks for that. I've removed it, although it hasn't fixed the problem.  I see that on the test file its failing to find the below element
button2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'///*[@id="topos-component"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/h3').click()
time.sleep(2)

Comment: Simply removing it isn't going to help. The point is that you need to sleep after clicking that last button, you thought you were, but you weren't. Add a sleep in a place that actually sleeps, or use a better solution than sleeping.

Comment: Okay thanks, to be fair I don't think the sleep is causing the issue. The problem is with not being able to join the browser session thats already been launched through the login function. So in the test file, when it searches for an xpath after the login method has been run it can't find it. Hope this makes sense..

Comment: The session doesn't reset or logout or anything after the function returns. If you replace the call to the function with just the function body, the result will be the same. Selenium knows nothing about functions. The button just isn't present at the time. Suppose you didn't have this login business. How would you debug the program? Take a screenshot or get the HTML source or something so that you can see what the driver is seeing.